# System settings" Display"

Tags: 16.04

I changed my display setting as i used different resolution monitor. Once i changed the resolution back and used my previous monitor. The display is not restoring to the previous settings.

Answer (score 0):

$ xrandr -q
you will get the display devices connected to your system. E.g. : VGA - 0 or HDMI - 0,...

Note down the display name and enter it in the below command(replacing VGA1) and the appropriate scale(replacing 1.5)

$ xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1024×768 --scale 1.5x1.5

Note: 'x' used in resolution is not multiplication sign. It is alphabet x